# Get image from image view in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have two images as drawables, one for checked, and one for unchecked.

When the user clicks on a button, I want to swap these views in the ImageView.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you need to be a little more clear about your question and add some relevant code or this will surely be closed

Comment: Please can you clarify what you're trying to ask?

Comment: i have one button and one image view,and src of image is one of two image in drawable folder.i want when user clicked on button i find out what image set to imageview and change to another image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setImageResource` method of the `ImageView` in conjunction with a class variable that holds the resource id of the current image:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.my_image_view );

switch( mCurrentImage )
{
    case R.drawable.image1:
        iv.setImageResource( R.drawable.image2 );
        mCurrentImage = R.drawable.image2;
    break;
    case R.drawable.image2:
        iv.setImageResource( R.drawable.image1 );
        mCurrentImage = R.drawable.image1;
    default:
}
```

Comment: i want to understand what image was set to image view,after that with above code set new image

Comment: sorry i forgot to said to  you that i work with listview and i dont think so this work in listview that i worked??i show this in list view and i want when user cliked on row image of that change

Comment: Use `onListItemClicked`, you get the View that was clicked on.  Find the ImageView inside that View.